# Kotlin package structure in intelliJ Idea

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup kotlin unit test with gradle build system in IntelliJ IDE by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJRZvnz979o&t=107s). I have created an project named *test.sample* which contains only src folder by default.

[image]

Then in the intelliJ terminal I created a gradle project manually.

[image]

Now my problem is after creating the gradle project it creates main and test folder inside src file, but i'm getting import package error as you can see in the below image.

[image]

The error disappears if i change the import path to ***main.kotlin.test.sample*** but i want the import should be test.sample. How do i exclude main.kotlin from package directory.

Comment: I think this goes in direction of source sets and build flavors - "main" is just your main source set - I am not sure if you _should_ force your structure to be against gradle and the flavor system. sometimes it's better to work _with_ the given structures instead of fighting them

Comment: @Grisgram I'm curious how he is doing that here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJRZvnz979o&t=107s

Comment: i didn't watch the entire video but he is creating a library, not an app and he also has the main... structure - sorry what's the point? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gradle or Maven, follow the standard directories layout for these build systems.

If you import the project in IntelliJ IDEA from `build.gradle`, it will set the source root to `src/main/kotlin` instead of `src` and your imports will work properly.